# Get long running google cloud speech api operation result later

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I am using the ruby api for google cloud speech api. The following code returns a operation object.

```
project_id = "xxx"
speech = Google::Cloud::Speech.new project: project_id
file_name = "test.flac"
audio = speech.audio file_name, encoding: :flac, sample_rate: 44100,language: "en-US"
operation = audio.process words: true
```

With `operation.wait_until_done!` I could poll the operation till it is finished. However my audio files are about 30 minutes long. So this will block my processes for a very long time.

Is it possible to get the result of a operation later? I know  I can call `operation.id` to get an unique identifier for the operation. Is it possible to use this one later to get the results of a operation?

Comment: I found a non ruby solution via the REST API. You have to call this URL: https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/operations/{name}, name is the operation.id value. Does anybody know how long the result of the transformation is kept on Googles server. Is it possible to call this URL above for example 1 week later?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem. 
Basically, you can access the operation via a standard RestAPI call. Seems a strange way of doing it, but it works.

[ugly solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980266/save-google-cloud-speech-api-operationjob-object-to-retrieve-results-later)