# Check Google Speech API operation from Google Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-speech

I am using Google Speech API to transcript long files. The API is called from Google Cloud Functions. **I want to check the result of `longRunningRecognize` later with [operations.get](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/operations/get)**. I know the `name/id` of the operation, but i cannot find a good way to check the status of operation from Google Cloud Function by the operation name.

Of course, i can just make a GET HTTP request to this url:

```
https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/operations/{name}?key=API_KEY
```

This is an example code that works:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');
const request = require('request');

exports.transcribe = functions.storage.object().onFinalize((object) => {
  // some code to get data required for speech API
  const payload = {
    audio: {
      uri: 'some_uri/to/google/storage/file'
    },
    config: {
      encoding: 'FLAC',
      languageCode: 'en-US'
    }
  };

  const client = new speech.SpeechClient({
    projectId: 'my-project-id'
  });

  client.longRunningRecognize(payload)
    .then(responses => {
      const operation = responses[0];
      // current example of getting operation status by operation name with HTTP call
      request(`https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/operations/${operation.latestResponse.name}?key=MY-API-KEY`, (error, response, body) => {
        console.log('Operation status response: ', body);
      });
    });
});
```

But it seems like there should be a more clear way of doing this. At least
I can find this [ruby way of getting operation status](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46004019/1274503) and this description of [OperationsClient](http://googleapis.github.io/gax-nodejs/OperationsClient.html), so i want something like this to check the status:

```
// this line is the most confusing part of the puzzle
const client = longrunning.operationsClient();
const name = '';
client.getOperation({name: name}).then(function(responses) {
  var response = responses[0];
  // doThingsWith(response)
});
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you've moved on, but I'll answer for the sake of others.

When you run the `longRunningRecognize` method, the SDK starts polling longrunning `operations.get` for you. You just need to set up a node event listener using `.on`.

The `Operation` object (first array element of the promise returned from longRunningRecognize) emits node events on `progress`, `complete` and `error`.

An update of OP's code:

```
client.longRunningRecognize(payload)
  .then(responses => {
    const operation = responses[0];
    operation.on('progress', (metadata, apiResponse) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(metadata))
    });
  });
```

Example output: (same as `https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/operations/...`)

```
{"startTime":{"seconds":"1529629181","nanos":790333000},"lastUpdateTime":{"seconds":"1529629182","nanos":661910000}}
{"progressPercent":26,"startTime":{"seconds":"1529629181","nanos":790333000},"lastUpdateTime":{"seconds":"1529629245","nanos":48465000}}
{"progressPercent":52,"startTime":{"seconds":"1529629181","nanos":790333000},"lastUpdateTime":{"seconds":"1529629307","nanos":516891000}}
{"progressPercent":78,"startTime":{"seconds":"1529629181","nanos":790333000},"lastUpdateTime":{"seconds":"1529629369","nanos":680341000}}
```

Note that there is no apparent way to get the partially transcribed text with an async operation, only the status percentage.

Answer (score 0):

[I just ran into a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66130631/how-do-serialize-and-deserialize-a-longrunningrecognize-operation-to-get-its-r/66192218).

Here's the code you're looking for to check the status of a `longRunningRecognize` with an operation name:

```js
const client = new speech.SpeechClient();
const operationName = '...';
client.checkLongRunningRecognizeProgress(operationName).then(res => {
  if(res.done){
    var response = res.result.responses[0];
    // doThingsWith(response)
  }
});
```