# How do serialize and deserialize a `longRunningRecognize` operation to get its result later?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech, google-speech-to-text-api

I'm using firebase cloud functions to transcribe user-uploaded audio files with [the example code for `longRunningRecognize`](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize#transcribing_long_audio_files_using_a_local_file):

```js
// Detects speech in the audio file. This creates a recognition job that you
// can wait for now, or get its result later.
const [operation] = await client.longRunningRecognize(request);

// Get a Promise representation of the final result of the job
const [response] = await operation.promise();
```

This code works fine for short audio files that can be transcribed faster than the [9-minute firebase cloud function maximum execution limit](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#time_limits), but 1) many of my ~hour-long user-uploaded files don't get transcribed that quickly, and 2) it seems wasteful to have a cloud function [getting billed for each tenth of a second it's running](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#compute_time) just sitting around waiting for an API response.

I think the obvious fix here would be for [Google's Speech-to-Text API](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/) to support webhooks.

Until that happens, **how can I serialize and deserialize the `SpeechClient` `operation` so I can get the result of this transcription job later from a [scheduled function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions)?**

Specifically, I'm looking for something that would work like the made-up `SERIALIZE` and `DESERIALIZE` functions in this example:

```js
// start speech recognition job:
const [operation] = await client.longRunningRecognize(request);
const serializedOperation = operation.SERIALIZE();
db.doc("jobs/job1").set(serializedOperation);

// get the result later in a scheduled function:
const snap = await db.doc("jobs/job1").get();
const serializedOperation = snap.data();
const operation = DESERIALIZE(serializedOperation);
const [response] = await operation.promise();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Brendan for the pointer to [`GetOperation`](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rpc/google.longrunning#operations)—that was the linchpin I needed to figure this out.

Serializing an `operation` is trivially easy: just call `operation.name` and you'll get the operation's unique ID.

Deserializing an `operationName` with the `@google-cloud/speech` node library was SO FRUSTRATINGLY DIFFICULT to figure out how to do but I finally figured it out.

To check on the status of an `Operation` and get its result from an `operation.name`, use `client.checkLongRunningRecognizeProgress(operation.name)` like this:

```js
const operation = await client.checkLongRunningRecognizeProgress(operationName);
if(operation.done) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(operation.result));
} else {
  const {progressPercent, startTime, lastUpdateTime} = op.metadata;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[LongRunningRecognize](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.speech.v1#speech) returns an Operation. [Operation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rpc/google.longrunning#operation) name is unique.

You could save the Operation name somewhere and then at a later time call [GetOperation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rpc/google.longrunning#operations)